# How to manipulate a Variable from another class using a method call from that other class?

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class Main{
.
.
.
Class class = new Class();
class.method(class.variableFromAnotherClass);
sysout(class.variableFromAnotherClass)
}

public class Class{
Int variableFromAnotherClass=0;

method(int var){
    var=1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Im dealing with a situation similar to the one above except with more variables in my version of "Class". My issue is that the method within "Class" does nothing to the variable being passed through. Why does this happen? Is it because the variable being passed through already belongs to the class? Any suggestions on What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: ^^^^^ exact dupe please vote people. Further more, the code cannot even compile...

Comment: It isn't doing anything with `var`. You need to set `method()` to either return a value or change an instance variable in `Class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing has to do with Java passing variables by *reference*, instead of by *value*. when `variableFromAnotherClass` is passed into `class.method(int var)`, the `int var` variable is created from a copy of `variableFromAnotherClass`. so when `var=1` is called, it updates the copy of `variableFromAnotherClass`, and not `variableFromAnotherClass` itself.

If you want to be able to change `variableFromAnotherClass` from `Main`, you can write `class.variableFromAnotherClass=1;` instead of calling `method`.

Another, more professional way of updating variables is using getters and setters:

```
public class Class {

    int variableFromAnotherClass;

    public void getVar() {
        return variableFromAnotherClass;
    }

    public int setVar(int var) {
        this.variableFromAnotherClass = var;
    }

}
```

Comment: Downvoted as this is misleading.  Java is very much pass by _value_, it's just that for non-primitive types that value _is_ a reference.  I suspect the duplicate question's answer can put this much better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

please make both the method and the variable static

```
public class Class{
static Int variableFromAnotherClass=0;

static method(int var){
    var=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try java getters and setter and make instance variables of another class private which will add encapsulation.